# Import ionic salesforce mobile application into android studio, SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, salesforce

There is a problem in creating Salesforce mobile application using ionic, I followed the tutorial of trealhead [Trailhead Ionic](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/mobile-sdk-hybrid-apps/steps/mobilesdk-hybrid-apps-04)
When I import my project into the android studio i get this problem:

[image: No resource found that matches the given name ( at 'icon' with value '@drawable/sf__icon)]

Please don't mark it as duplicate because I saw all of the issues posted and no one treat the problem of Salesforce Mobile SDK.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a PNG called sf__icon.png under:

Platforms/android/res/drawable

To get going, just copy one of the icons from one of the other folders inside res.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is not good solution. If it works in simple android project doesn't mean that it will works android project implementing Salesforce Mobile SDK. This is the first solution i tought about. Whenever you add the directory with sf__icon.png the error disappear, But the app will not be started ( app has been stoped). Thanks Adam for answering this issue.